# My microphone goes to my own speakers not partner

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, skype, microphone

I just installed Skype on Ubuntu 16.04. Now not only in Skype but also other applications like Firefox Hello I do hear my own voice (mic) on my own speakers (I have a headset). The microphone is not broadcasted/sent to my conversation's partner.

How can I stop the microphone being sent to my own headset? Of course, I want the mic to be "routed" to the person I am talking to.

I already played around with pavucontrol and the Ubuntu sound controls, but no success.